# How to determine if there is any ongoing network usage on a BlackBerry smartphone?

Tags: blackberry

I'm writing an application that needs to perform some tasks only if there is no ongoing network usage by other applications/system.

There is this cute little arrow in the upper right corner that shows it, but of course, I need to check it programatically. Is there any function in the API that would allow me to do so?

I'm developing for BB OS 6.0. I have searched Stack Overflow and google with no luck. I would appreciate pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is controlled by the OS and AFAIK there's no way to check it from your app's code. But as you have pointed out, there's that arrow in the top right corner. If you could take a screenshot and the top bar appeared in it, you could detect the network activity in a given instant.

Using the APIs the only thing you can do is to check for connectivity. If there is no coverage, you can be sure there is no network traffic (but at the same time you can't use the network). You can also count the number of sent or received packets using `RadioInfo` class.

Comment: Isn't `RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived()` and `RadionInfo. getNumberOfPacketsSent()` exactly what he/she wants?  He can just create a background Thread to poll for those two values at some constant rate?  It just seems like the last sentence is conflicting with the rest of your answer, and might hide your very good insight from people who start reading your first paragraph and give up.

Comment: @Nate Not sure what exactly he/she wants. The total number of packets sent or received says nothing about whether or not there's network activity at a given moment. It is information about the past, he needs info about the present. But even if he manages to detect it, there's no way to prevent another app making connections at the very moment his app starts.

Comment: well, no API on any platform tells you what other applications are *about to start doing*, right?  if you operate on the assumption that the poster understands this limitation of the time dimension, it seems reasonable to conclude that the very recent past (say, the last few seconds) would be a decent proxy for *the present*.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments. I was wondering whether it was possible to receive information about transmission events in a way similiar to receiving information about signal level changes (which can be done by implementing `RadioStatusListener` interface). I of course understand that this way it is only possible to obtain informations about the recent past, but this is not a problem - I only reed a rough estimation. I guess I'll go with a backgroud thread polling for numbers of packet received and sent, as @Mister Smith and @Nate suggested.